# Different APs can be assign gateway from different brand

Tags: wireless, gateway, default-gateway

Edge-core EWS101 can be assign as gateway for EnGenius ENS202 APs ?
Different brands will be work as gateway for wireless controller ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, wireless controllers can only control compatible WAPs from the same vendor. So that won't work.

For a network-layer/IP gateway (router), you can likely use anything you want.

Comment: If i configure as gateway, still the captive portal and other features can work?

Comment: The gateway doesn't matter, the *wireless controller* controls those things and that controller must support the WAPs.